# How to get static resources from assembly's referenced assembly

Tags: c#, .net-assembly, system-codedom-compiler

I got an assembly, created by System.CodeDomCompiler at runtime. The compiled assembly use a referenced assembly. Further i declare CodeDomAssembly as my compiled assembly at runtime, and RefAssembly as the referenced assembly used by CodeDomAssembly.

In the RefAssembly is a static class called KeyHavester with static List and static propertys/methods. The CodeDomAssembly contains WPF-forms. I call these forms like this:

```
RefType = CodeDomAssembly.GetType("formname");
CodeDomAssembly.CreateInstance(.....);
MethodInfo = RefType.GetMethod("ShowDialog");
bool? dialogresult = (bool?)MethodInfo.Invoke(RefType , new object[] { });
```

Okay so far it works..
After the form returns with a dialogresult, there are colleced keys in KeyHavester Class. The static class KeyHavester hold all the keys and is a referenced assembly to the CodeDomAssembly. So i thought this should be accessable like this:

```
RefType = CodeDomAssembly.GetType("KeyHavester"); //static class in RefAssembly
MethodInfo = RefType.GetMethod("GetKeys"); //GetKeys() return a List<string>
```

All i get is RefType == null. So how to access the static KeyHavester Class in the RefAssembly trough the CodeDomAssembly?

Does the RefAssembly need a public Token? RefAssembly = {FunktionBibliothek, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null}

How i get this to work?

Comment: There is no real point in using Reflection in codedom-compiled code.  You can use the real type names, as long as you get the CompileParameters correct to add the reference assemblies.  Also avoids the likely mistakes in the snippet, "KeyHavester" surely lives in a namespace.  Or was just mis-spelled from "harvester".

Comment: My Application compiles code at runtime. Then i want to use it.. so i cant use the real type names, because the application wont compile. I forgot the 'r' in KeyHavester yes, but its not the problem. The RefAssembly is referenced by the CodeDomAssembly.